# ¿Como puedo crear un grid en java, que me permita autofiltrar los datos como en dev express?

Tags: java

Quisiera saber si existe alguna alternativa a grid view en java, que me permita realizar varias funciones como autofiltros, o personalizar al maximo de manera menos tediosa. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Al ser una app de escritorio y no concretar que usas [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) vamos a contar que tienes [swing](/questions/tagged/swing), el standard (por ahora) que viene con java y netbeans.

Para ello necesitas una [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) con [`RowSorter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html) para realizar la ordenación, aparte usaremos:

- un [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) con datos para rellenar la tabla
- Un [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) para poderlo mostrar

---

Primero los datos a mostrar (esto en tu aplicacion lo puedes realizar dinamicamente recogiendo datos de la BBDD)

```
// titulos
private final static String nombresDeColumna[] = 
        { "Nombre", "Apellido", "Edad" };

// datos
private final static Object[][] datos = { 
        { "Jordi", "Castilla", 35 },
        { "Mymike", "Mine", 25 }, 
        { "Luiggi", "Mendoza", 40 },
        { "Super", "Falete", 60 } };
```

Ahora la clase `main`. Para no enrollarme y sea más facil de entender voy a comentar entre lineas

```
// creamos el modelo con los datos 
TableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(datos, nombresDeColumna) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    }
};

// creamos la Table basados en el modelo de datos que hemos creado
JTable table = new JTable(modelo);

// ordenacion de filas (por defecto, al ser tipos primitivos)
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(modelo);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);

// creamos un scroll y le añadomos la tabla
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

// contenedor principal 
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tabla con filtros");
// le decimos que cierre 
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
// añadimos la tabla
frame.add(scrollPane);
// tamaño
frame.setSize(500, 150);
// mostramos
frame.setVisible(true);
```

---

El resultado, como puedes ver es una tabla con columnas ordenables e intercambiables

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[Codigo de muestra en IDEONE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html) 
*(no puedes ejecutarlo online ya que no tiene motor gráfico)*

---

**NOTAS:**

- Imports necesarios

  ```
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
  import javax.swing.JTable;
  import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
  import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
  import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
  ```
- Espero que nadie se ofenda por la edad `:P` jejejeje
- Si tienes dudas, [sílbame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QO7KYyDSkXA) `:)`.

Comment: Hola Jordi, asi es uso Swing, mas bien Swingx. y tu codigo si lo entiendo, pero mas bien voy a corregir mi pregunta, lo que busco es una alternativa   a los grid view de Dev Express, pero de codigo abierto. Lo que quiero obtener es un grid con una fila de autofiltro mas que nada. Por ejemplo:         https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/HelpResource.ashx?help=WindowsForms&document=img4005.jpg      GRACIAS!!